# Why timeout not working linux server

Tags: php, linux, timeout, exec

I have a executable and I want to run it using timeout. I am using linux server and php. Following is the code i am using

```
exec("timeout 2s ./exe < input > output");
```

It just produce output file with no content. But if I remove timeout as below:

```
exec("./exe < input > output");
```

then it shows the expected output in my output file.

Why this is happening. Am I using timeout in the right way. 
How to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the timeout to 5 or 10 seconds?

Comment: yes i just tried... but still no

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your command the following way:

```
exec("timeout 2s ./exe < input > output 2>&1");
```

It could be that `timeout` is not on the `PATH`.

Comment: You can either change the `PATH` under which `php` operates (difficult) or call the command by absolute path (easier).

Comment: how do I know the absolute path... please help cause I am new to this area

Comment: Typically the timeout command is in `/usr/bin/timeout`. To check you can call the command `which timeout` in a shell on the system you're running PHP on.

Comment: that means from php
<?php
echo exec("which timeout");

?>

Comment: No that means from a regular terminal session on your Linux server. But as a last resort the PHP variant should also work to get the information.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may be that the `timeout` command is not existing on your system or not found by PHP, because it is not in your PATH.